# Compare two files, using confidence interval

Tags: python

I have two files, with 3 columns each, I need to compare the lines with the common first column word, and then compare second and third column and only accept the lines with a confidence interval of +2 in second column, and -2 in the third column, example:

File 1:

```
n1  11  19 # 11 (within +2 confidence) 19 (-2) repect to first n1 in file 2 (10 20).
n2  20  30 # no n2 in file 2, discard.
```

File 2:

```
n1  10  20       
n1  30  40   # outside confidence interval (+2 -2) respect to n1 in file 1.
```

Output:

```
n1  11  19
```

I thought of using the "range" function to generate the intervals:

```
a=[1]   
range(a, a+3) # +2 to second column (e.g. 10,11,12) 
b=[2]
range(b, b-3, -1) # -2 to third column (e.g. 20,19,18)
```

But I didn't found the way to implement it, any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The labels are unique in each file, no repetitions? --- The order of the labels in the two files is independent or they are sorted or otherwise ordered? --- how big are your files (i guess 10**5 lines is not _really_big)?

Comment: the order of the labels is independent and could be repeat, file 2 can contain 4 n2, but only one of them (in e.g) can match with a n2 from file 1.

Comment: I don't see any reference to `biopython`, so I don't think the tag should be there

Comment: hello cd98, you are right, tag deleted.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, the late clarification.  Please disregard my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a mouthful, but by using Pandas it will probably be easier to modify.

First add each column of file 1 and file 2 into a pandas dataframe (if you have them as .txt files, then `pd.read_csv(file_name)` will read them into a dataframe)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"file1A" : [11, 20],
                   "file1B" : [19, 30], "file2A": [10, 30],
                   "file2B" : [20, 40]})
```

Which looks like

```
    file1A  file1B  file2A  file2B
0     11     19        10     20
1     20     30        30     40
```

Then just select the rows that satisfy your requirement:

```
df[(df.file2A - 2 < df.file1A) & (df.file1A < df.file2A + 2) & 
   (df.file2B - 2 < df.file1B) & (df.file1B < df.file2B + 2) ]
```

gives

```
    file1A  file1B  file2A  file2B
0     11      19      10      20
```

Comment: hello cd98, the problem is that I have around half million of lines, I cant do that by hand.

Comment: What do you mean "by hand"? If it's just two columns and two files, then it's easy to read the `.txt` files into pandas to get into the shape above. The selection would be done exactly with the two lines I showed. Maybe I'm missing something, but if you give me a bit more detail I can edit my answer to include that.